# Learning code of drawing diagrams

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I am trying to learn the code of drawing a diagram like this. Is there a book to read to learn about the code of it? Thanks!

Comment: You could start with https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd and of course the `tikz` manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original picture is done with `xy` package (you can see the tips). There is also the possibility to build commutative diagrams also with `amscd` but they are a bit old packages even if I prefer them instead of the common package named `tikz-cd` as mentioned by the good user **@Dr. Manuel Kuehner** :-).
Here there is the code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
Q \ar@/_1pc/[ddr]_j \ar@/^/[drr]^{m} \ar@/^1pc/[drrr]^{i}\\
& A \ar[d]_p \ar[r]^q & B \ar[d]_q  \ar[r]^g &  C \ar[d]^r\\
& X \ar[r]_u & Y  \ar[r]_v & Z}
\end{document}
```

and your output is this:

[image]

If you don't like the tips of the vectors defining your commutative graph I suggest to use the `cmtip` option and you will have the same look as `tikz-cd`. If you want to center your graph I recommend `\[` code `\]` within the `\xymatrix` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
Q \ar@/_1pc/[ddr]_j \ar@/^/[drr]^{m} \ar@/^1pc/[drrr]^{i}\\
& A \ar[d]_p \ar[r]^q & B \ar[d]_q  \ar[r]^g &  C \ar[d]^r\\
& X \ar[r]_u & Y  \ar[r]_v & Z}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And a link: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix

Comment: @Teepeemm Certainly, you can edit my answer if you prefer. You are welcome. In the meantime I prepare homework for my students :-)

Answer (score 4):

To complement Sebastiano's very good answer, here's an implementation with `tikz-cd`

Like in Xy-pic, you have to think to the diagram as a matrix and instruct to draw arrows with `r` for “right”, `d` for “down”, so specifying the target cell. The label goes between double quotes and the `'` after the closing quotes means “swap the label position” (normally to the left of the arrow).

With `bend left=20` the arrow is slightly bent to the left (think like for rivers, left and right are determined by imagining to be at the source and looking towards the end).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
Q \arrow[rdd,bend right=20,"j"']
  \arrow[rrd,bend left=20,"m"']
  \arrow[rrrd,bend left=20,"i"] \\
& A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d,"p"]
& B \arrow[r,"g"] \arrow[d,"q"]
& C \arrow[d,"r"] \\
& X \arrow[r,"u"'] & Y \arrow[r,"v"'] & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahahah but it's not true that mine is a good answer, let's say it's old. When I create code with xy package I always think of you. You don't like the package tips because when you see them your heart bleeds. ahahahahh

Comment: At least you suggested `cmtip`. ;-)

Comment: In fact, I have put it in just thinking about you using cmtip...ahahahah. The resolution of your image is spectacular.

Answer (score 2):

And just as another alternative, you don't need to add very much to plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) to produce reasonable looking commutative diagrams.  Although I think I could only recommend this approach if you are already using MP elsewhere in your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
% draw labelled arrow along Path
vardef labelled_arrow(expr Path, Label, Offset, Time) = 
    drawarrow Path 
        cutbefore fullcircle scaled 14 shifted point 0 of Path
        cutafter  fullcircle scaled 18 shifted point infinity of Path;
    draw thelabel(Label, origin) scaled 0.8 shifted point Time of Path 
        shifted (unitvector(direction Time of Path rotated 90) scaled Offset);
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    x1 = x4; 
    x2 = x5;
    x3 = x6;

    y1 = y2 = y3;
    y4 = y5 = y6;

    x3 - x2 = x2 - x1 = y1 - y4  = 48;

    z0 = origin;
    z1 = 52 dir -56;

    numeric i; i=-1;
    forsuffixes @=Q, A, B, C, X, Y, Z: 
        label("$" & str @ & "$", z[incr i]); 
    endfor

    interim ahangle := 20; % very pointy arrows...

    labelled_arrow(z1--z2, "$f$", 6, 1/2);
    labelled_arrow(z2--z3, "$g$", 5, 1/2);
    labelled_arrow(z4--z5, "$u$", -5, 1/2);
    labelled_arrow(z5--z6, "$v$", -5, 1/2);
    labelled_arrow(z1--z4, "$p$", 5, 1/2);
    labelled_arrow(z2--z5, "$q$", 5, 1/2);
    labelled_arrow(z3--z6, "$r$", 5, 1/2);

    labelled_arrow(z0 {right}   .. z3, "$i$",  6, 3/8);
    labelled_arrow(z0 {down}    .. z4, "$j$", -5, 3/8);
    labelled_arrow(z0 {dir -10} .. z2, "$m$", -6, 3/8);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Extra note

And those who prefer TeX style arrows, can add this:

```
input cmarrows
setup_cmarrows(arrow_name = "texarrow"; parameter_file = "cmr6.mf"; macro_name = "drawarrow");
```

before the `beginfig(1)` to get a version like this:

[image]

For more on `cmarrows` see [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmarrows?lang=en).

Comment: Very nice answer.....+1. Look the q..it is seem to be to left of the diagram...and also the p.

Comment: My bad, apparently I was following egreg not the OP.  But `labelled_arrow(z1--z4, "$p$", -5, 1/2);` would put the label on the other side.

Comment: Ah, don't worry :-) my it was only an advice.